# Trying to print form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I've done some more work on printing forms in C# since my last question, I've got this code now:

```
    public void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);            
        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);             


        PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
        doc.PrintPage += this.Doc_PrintPage;

        PrintDialog dlgSettings = new PrintDialog();
        dlgSettings.Document = doc;

        if (dlgSettings.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            doc.Print();
        }
    }

    private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        float x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        float y = e.MarginBounds.Top;

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap);
    }
```

Where printToolStripMenuItem_Click is the print button. I know I'm close because I saw the print dialogue before I edited the code to fit my needs. Right now, I'm getting an error that says "bitmap" in "e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap);" doesn't exist in context.

What can I change to make this print the image? I'm trying to print the image of the screen before I try creating the print document, because this seems easier, and just incase it works. I'm lazy sometimes :P

Note: This is all code inside my form2.cs file, the form I need to print.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring bitmap in `printToolStripMenuItem_Click` but using it in `Doc_PrintPage`. You need to pass it some way. The easiest way would be to make it an instance variable (i.e. declare it in the class instead of the method, then assign it in `printToolStripMenuItem_Click`).

```
public class SomeForm
{
  private Bitmap bitmap;
  public void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //...
    bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
    //...
  }
}
```

You also are missing a parameter in the `e.Graphics.DrawImage` call. You need to specify where to draw the image. For instance, if you want it in the upper left corner do:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0,0));
```

Comment: No; use an anonymous method with a closure.

Comment: That would work too, but you should probably leave an answer describing how to do that. I figured simplest is best for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the imformative answer! I tried this, but I got an error on the line `e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap);` saying `No overload for method 'DrawImage' takes 1 arguments`

Comment: You need to give it a location to draw the bitmap. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1.aspx for more information.

Comment: Perfect, I got it to work, but this method is definetely not going to work. I'll need to create a form just for printing I think. Ill post new questions when they arise, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use an anonymous method to create an event handler *inside* your function.
This way, it will still be able to read your local variables, through the magic of closures.

```
doc.PrintPage += (s, e) => {
    float x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
    float y = e.MarginBounds.Top;

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap);
};
```